# Making a form not submit on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have

```
<form action="reviews/review" method="POST" name="#load">

        Review Author:
        <br />
        <input name="author" size="8" type="text" class="userpass"/>
        <br /><br />

        Company Name:
        <br />
        <input name="company" size="8" type="text" class="userpass"/>
        <br /><br />

        Review Comment:
        <br />
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea>
        <br /><br />

        <input type="hidden" name="date" size="8" type="text" class="userpass" value="<? echo '$reviews[date]' ?>"/>     

        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Post Review" />

    </form>
```

it runs on an ajax page, the div of all info is submitted inside the `#load` div. When i go to validate the information, it refreshes and alerts that fields are empty. How can i make sure it doesn't refresh ?

the full AJAX is located here: http://pastebin.com/SzedcajU

Any ideas? I have it validating on the PHP side: http://pastebin.com/1xh0Le64

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the form to refresh, then don't tell it to redirect...

Instead of: `<form action="reviews/review" method="POST" name="#load">`

Use: `<form action="javascript: void(0);" method="POST" name="#load">`

Comment: what is the function of void(0)?

Comment: @CodeSlayer In this case, it's just one of those things you can do to basically do nothing. Another solution I've seen is simply "javascript:;"

Comment: @BaileyHerbert yes, but I need that `reviews/review` to be there so when i hit submit, it submits the information.

Comment: Well, from what I understand of your question (which doesn't make much sense, by the way) your form is redirecting before the data can be pulled out of it by JavaScript. The solution is to remove the reviews/review, and redirect [after] the form is processed.